# When did answers stop being sorted by upvotes (and why did this happen)?

Tags: support

During the last couple of weeks (as of April 2013), I've noticed that answers on the Stack Exchange Network no longer appear to be sorted by upvotes. Is this an intentional feature of the site, or is it a bug? If this is intentional, then what was the rationale for implementing it?

[image: This is rather surprising.]

[Here's the question with the screenshot that is shown above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520131/looking-for-a-good-world-map-generation-algorithm?rq=1).

Comment: The top right of your screenshot appears to indicate that you have the "Active" sort tab selected. Clicking on "Votes" should change it back to what you expect.

Comment: @eldarerathis OK, that basically solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @eldarerathis I recommend posting that as an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you click on "Votes" at the top right of the screenshot, it will cause the questions to be sorted by votes again.